# Problem with elasticsearch queries like Q, term and terms

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

```
client = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=client,index="myntra_clothes")

fts_query = MultiMatch(query=data['text'], fields=['Title', 'Description'], operator="AND", fuzziness='AUTO')
s = s.query(fts_query)
s = s.filter('match', SubCategory3='Jeans')
result = s.execute()
```

While the above works just fine,
Following is the list I tried, that won't work:

```
s = s.filter('terms', Colour['Blue','Black'])

q = Q('term', Category='Men') &  Q('term', SubCategory3='Jeans')
s = s.query(q)

es_query = []
es_query.append(Q("match", Category="Male"))
es_query.append(Q("match",SubCategory3="Jeans"))
final_query = Q("bool", must=es_query)
s = s.query(final_query)
```

These queries execute without throwing any error, just returns a blank response.

Update:
I am using Django framework and follow is my mapping:

```
@registry.register_document
class MyntraClothesDocument(Document):

class Index:
    # Name of the Elasticsearch index
    name = 'myntra_clothes'
    settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                'number_of_replicas': 0}

class Django:
    # The Django model associated with this Document
    model = MyntraClothes 

    # The fields of the model you want to be indexed in Elasticsearch
    fields = ['SubCategory3','Category','Colour','Title','Description']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second query, you are using [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) or [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html). **Both these queries work on exact matches**

The term/terms query does not apply any analyzer to the search term, so will only look for that exact term in the inverted index.

To search for the exact term, you need to use the `Category.keyword` field OR change the mapping of the field. The search result will come if `"Blue"` OR `"Black"` terms are are present in the index.

Whereas in the first query you are using [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), which analyzes the text (using [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified) while performing the search queries, therefore you are getting search results in the first query.

Comment: q2 = Q("terms", Colour.keyword=['Blue','Black']) , tried this but gives keyword can't be an expression. Please can you explain that with an example? Also, how to map the same in index

Comment: @Sachin have you defined any explicit index mapping ?

Comment: yes, I mapped the fields that I am using for searching from the database, and the above fields are so mapped.

Comment: @Sachin can you please share your index mapping? Also, it would be better if you can share some sample index data along with the expected search result

Comment: Thanks, I already found the solution. I was not explicitly mapping, I was using default mapping that highlevel elasticsearch client gives.

Comment: @Sachin if u were using the default mapping, then my answer works well in that case. Can you please tell what solution helped u resolves your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with implicit mapping that Django-Elasticsearch-Dsl does. After explicitly mapping the fields as keyword, queries were working just fine.
Here is the documents.py  and how I mapped:

```
SubCategory3 = fields.TextField(
                   fields={'raw': fields.KeywordField()},
                   analyzer="keyword")
```

My models defined SubCategory3 as TextField, so Elasticsearchs mapping had it as TextField by default. So providing mapping solves the problem.